# Why swpd is above 0 but si & so = 0 all the time

Tags: centos, vmstat

I've been monitoring my Centos with vmstat 1
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Here is the output:
[image]
So why swpd is above 0 but si & so = 0 all the time
Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The `swpd` column shows the amount of swap in use, the `si` and `so` columns show the swap activity in the time period represented by each line. In your example, you’re using 39,868 KiB of swap, but nothing is causing any swap activity so `si` and `so` are zero.

Comment: Hi Stephen Kitt. Thanks for replying. But for me this situation is not clear because there is a planty amount of free RAM.

Comment: That’s fine, the fact that there is lots of free memory doesn’t mean swap won’t be used (for pages which are *never* used at all and therefore don’t need to be in physical memory). [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417855/86440) provides some background.