# How to think about swap space allocation?

Tags: debian, swap, virtual-memory

**Q.** How do you think about how much swap space to allocate?

Does Linux (Debian 10 in this case) need enough swap space to swap out some VM pages plus more to swap in other pages, and thus the RAM + swap file size needs to be considerably larger than the total working set in order to not thrash badly?

**Assumptions:**

- Consider worker machines on Google Compute Engine, each running one payload process at a time and needing only one CPU. Rules-of-thumb for desktop machines don't apply.
- We can choose how many CPUs, disk GB, and RAM GB to allocate, but we pay for all that.
- Compute Engine N1 machines max out at 6.5 GB RAM/CPU so to get more memory we must either pay for more CPUs or enable swapping.
- Most of the payload processes fit in RAM but when a payload process needs more memory, we don't want it to fail or thrash badly.
- We can configure the swap space size (at the cost of more disk space) and the swappiness parameter.
- Ignore the contribution of memory-mapped files towards saving swap space.
- Hibernation doesn't apply.

What's a conceptual model for how Linux uses swap space so I can pick, debug, and tune it? Is VM size limited to the swap file size so every page has a place to swap out to and clean pages don't need to be written out? Or does VM size approach RAM + swap size? Or somewhere in between, where it needs a significant amount of swap space to write out some pages before swapping in others?

Comment: "would those payloads barely fit with 6.5 GB RAM + 4 GB swap space?" We don't know since we don't know the payloads. In my opinion, there is no valid rule of thumb for swap space. It all depends on the applications' behaviour, which means that you have to test it. You seem to think your workload swaps very rarely, in which case file swap rather than device swap might be a more flexible solution.

Comment: Perhaps a supplier that allows you to occasionally exceed your contracted loads would suit you better?

Comment: Thanks, @berndbausch. I'm asking for a conceptual model of how Linux uses swap space so I can design, debug, and tune; not for a rule of thumb. I replaced the example with I hope a better phrasing.

Comment: @JeremyBoden isn't that what swapping does? The limit is imposed by how Linux uses RAM.

Comment: You might find these Qs&As interesting: [Why does Linux need swap space in a VM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417855/86440) and [Swap memory, and when the OS starts using it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447911/86440).