# How do I limit the maximum RAM for Linux VPS?

Tags: debian, memory, cache, ram, buffer

I rent a shared VPS that runs Debian 9. I am alloted 4GB RAM (4096MB), but sometimes my processes go over 4GB. This is largely  due to the kernel caching a lot of my stuff, so I'd like to know if I can limit the kernel to 4GB so that when I need more RAM, it clears the buff/cache to ensure I don't go over 4GB. [image: Mem usage]
[image: free -m]

Comment: If you paste text as text, then +1. As it is blind people can not read the text. (A description alt-text for the remaining image would also be nice, but you will get my +1 without it).

Answer (score 2):

You already are limited to 4 GiB of memory; that’s what the “4096” value in the output of `free -m` means. Your graph is no doubt taking swap into account too, so when you see memory usage go over 4 GiB it’s because the sum of memory and swap used is greater than 4 GiB. (Either that, or it’s using powers of 10 rather than powers of 2.)

Comment: What is swap? Does it likely count against my 4GB plan that I pay for?

Comment: Swap is disk space which is used to supplement RAM in certain circumstances ([see here for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417872/86440)). It won’t count against the 4 GiB you’re paying for. It would be very unusual for a VPS to allow you to allocate more than you’re paying for, at least in my experience.